# HPE ProLiant DL60 Gen 9 - Please attach some optical or iLO media before continuing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, installation, hp-smart-array, provisioning

I'm trying to reinstall the OS on a HPE ProLiant DL60 Gen9 but it refuses to find the built in DVD drive.

I pressed F10 during boot (Provisioning) to install and after the "Select operation system" screen it says "Please attach some optical or iLO media before continuing"

The HP's branded Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials ROK disk is in the DVD drive, but it refuses to recognize it. I have read some where that I need to disable the Raid controller (B140i), but I can't find anywhere to do that.

I did this once before and at that point it worked fine...

Comment: If you select F9 when booting it should allow you to see all of the bootable-drive options, do you see your drive in that list?

Comment: The provisioning option typically reads from a SD Card reader tucked away inside the case.  HPE will thoughtfully load the card with installation image for the OS you purchase through them.  There are, of course, costs for the reader, the OS, the media (SD Card) and the loading of the image onto the media.  But you combine this with iLO, PXE, and a secure connection, and you can orchestrate from bare-metal to fully loaded from the other side of the world.  Try @Chopper3's suggestion.  F9 should get you into the settings.  There's another key for boot menu.  Watch the POST screens.

Comment: The thing is that when it was unboxed, I did install it from the DVD in the exact same way I'm trying now. But at that point it found the DVD player. The OS is HP's branded Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials ROK. I googled that I need to turn of the Raid controller, burt I can't find where to do this.

Comment: @Chopper3 The DVD is listed as "Embedded CD/DVD ROM: Dynamic Smart Array B104i - SATA Optical drive1"

Comment: Ok, thanks for that Max, well first of all you're going to HAVE to consciously boot from that CD drive via the F9 "One time boot" option but it'd be good to know a little more about your setup, have you disks connected to that same B104i or are they attached to a different disk controller?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally made it to find the DVD ROM. I did a Factory reset, disabled the internal SD card and changed boot order to:

Generic USB
DVD-ROM

I really don't think the boot order matters, but I was desperate. It did the trick, now the "Intelligent" Provisioning finally finds the DVD and I can install the OS.

Thank you everyone for your involvement...